# Why is my CSS class with "/" character failing in IE8 printing mode only?

Tags: html, css, printing, internet-explorer-8

I have a database table containing categories. They have a field containing abbreviations of the category names. I am currently using these abbreviations directly as CSS class names for html elements. They represent a graphic presentation of these categories, and I need to be able to print them. One of the abbreviation strings has a forward slash, like `AND/OR`. Now, forward slashes are not valid CSS class name characters, but instead of assigning class name differently, I simply added an escape character, and the problem was solved. The CSS class name is therefor `.AND\/OR` it works like a charm. Except for the printing preview, and printing itself in IE8.

This fiddle represents my problem area to the spot. JSFiddle does unfortunately not play very well along with IE8 either, though...
http://jsfiddle.net/FSvnj/1/

Note that all other CSS is working perfectly, so this is not an issue of needing to include background colors and images. I've already done that. I also have two seperate css files for printing and screen display, but I have triple checked that they are identical. The printing is even confirmed by tests in Chrome, so... Is this just (yet) another quirk from the famous and fantastic IE software, or am I doing something wrong?

I am developing for a company that uses Chrome and IE8 as standard, so I haven't tested in other IE versions.

Comment: Any chance you could take the easy way out and rename the class, like `.AND-OR`?

Comment: Also, it's curious that a company would still use IE8 as the standard. The only Windows version that runs IE8 is XP and Microsoft has just ended its support.

Comment: It is always a possibility, however I am currently using all abbreviations, which are database strings, directly as class names. I would prefer to stick to that standard, if I can. And yes, believe me, I have tried to tell my superiors that my work would be twice as efficient without this crazy browser's demands and quirks, but it seems they have good reasons to wait.

Comment: I have switched the database abbreviation now, and use a dash instead of forward slash. I tried to make a replace string in jstl, to keep the / in the visible text of the category, but I had a lot of issues. the colors and CSS now work, but ´AND-OR´ doesn't look as good as ´AND/OR´. If anyone has a explanation to why CSS is interpreted differently in IE8 screen view and printer view, I would be happy to learn something new.